# Show that $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin{(nx+3)}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ converges pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification, pointwise-convergence

I need to show that this sequence function converges pointwise with the help of ($\delta-\epsilon$) definition.

I tried to first split this sequence by sandwich theorem then I am stuck at applying pointwise convergence definition that how should I choose $\epsilon$ and $N$.

Comment: First you observe that it converges to the identically zero function. Second, note that $$
\left| {\frac{{\sin (nx + 3)}}{{\sqrt {n + 1} }} - 0} \right| = \left| {\frac{{\sin (nx + 3)}}{{\sqrt {n + 1} }}} \right| \le \frac{1}{{\sqrt {n + 1} }} < \varepsilon 
$$ whenever $n>?$...

Comment: Whenever n > 1/€^2 -1 ??? (1 over absilon square minus 1)

Comment: Yes, $n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}-1=:N$. Try learning LaTeX.

Comment: But our N doesn't involve x while definition of pointwise convergence says that N should depend on both absilon and x !!

Comment: It is a constant function of $x$. With that argument the constant $1$ function $f(x)=1$ would not be a function because it seemingly does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$|f_n(x)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ for all $x$ and all $n$. Hence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly (and hence pointwise) on $ \mathbb  R$ to $0$.

Can you proceed ?